# Do you unlock anything in the mercenaries in Resident Evil 4?

Tags: resident-evil-4-2005

I have played Seperate Ways and Assignment Ada in Resident Evil 4 and you unlock the Chicago Typewriter in one of them as something else in the other. Do you actually unlock anything in the Mercenaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Resident Evil 4 Wikia](http://residentevil.wikia.com/wiki/The_Mercenaries_(RE4)), you can unlock the [Handcannon](http://residentevil.wikia.com/wiki/Handcannon) by earning a 5-star ranking on every The Mercenaries stage with every character.

> The [Handcannon](http://residentevil.wikia.com/wiki/Handcannon) is unlocked when the player gets a 5-star ranking on
>   every stage with every character. To earn a 5-star ranking, a total of
>   60,000 or more points is required.